# Django UpdateView with three different modelforms

Tags: python, django

I have a django UpdateView which needs to inherit three different models and different models. CreateView is working fine with three different modelforms.

models.py:

```
class Employee(models.Model):
    """
    Create employee attributes
    """
    employee_user = models.OneToOneField(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    e_id = models.IntegerField(unique=True, null=True, blank=True)
    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128,blank=True)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, blank=True)
    .....
class WorkExperience(models.Model):
    """
    Stores employee previous work experiences
    """
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', related_name='we_employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    previous_company_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    job_designation = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    from_date = models.DateField(null=True)
     ......

class Education(models.Model):
    """
    Stores employee education background
    """
    employee = models.ForeignKey('Employee', related_name='edu_employee', on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    institution_name = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    degree = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
    .....
```

views.py:

```
class EmployeeUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    """
    Update a created a employee
    """
    login_url = '/authentication/login/'
    template_name = 'employee/employee_add_form.html'
    form_class = EmployeeAddModelForm
    work_form_class = WorkExperienceForm
    education_form_class = EducationForm
    queryset = Employee.objects.all()

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get_object(self):
        id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
        return get_object_or_404(Employee, id=id_)
```

WHen I go to Update view, I am only able to update EmployeeAddModelForm values. But other form's(WorkExperienceForm, EducationForm ) fields do not appear let alone edit the values of the fields.
I suppose my views.py is not correct.
I need suggestion to correct my updateview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to put multiple forms in one HTML file, in my way, write as follows.

```
class EmployeeUpdateView(LoginRequiredMixin,UpdateView):
    login_url = '/authentication/login/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        print(form.cleaned_data)
        return super().form_valid(form)

    def get(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    id_ = self.kwargs.get("id")
    user = Employee.objects.get(id=id_)
    work = WorkExperience.objects.get(employee=user)
    education = Education.objects.get(employee=user)


    return render(request, self.template_name, {
                                                'form': EmployeeAddModelForm(instance=user),
                                                'work_form': WorkExperienceForm(instance=work),
                                                'education_form': EducationForm(instance=education)
                                                }
                                            )


    def post(self, request):
    
        first_name = request.POST['first_name']
        # Your own code...
        .....
```

I think the argument of each form depends on the definition of Form.

And in a very simple way, the HTML file looks like this:

```
<body>
    <form method="post">
        {% csrf_token %}
        {{ employ_form }}
        {{ work_form }}
        {{ edu_form }}
        <button type="submit">OK</button>
    </form?
</body>
</html>
```

I'm not sure if this is the best option.

Comment: If i do this, I loose the prefilled values. I need to fill up the form again.

Comment: The get method displays three blank forms and the post method will process the values entered into the forms.

Comment: I got it. But when I want to edit an object, my form needs to get data from the database. i can not show blank forms for updating.

Comment: Dharman, I am sorry, I was wrong. I forgot this case was "UpdateView". I will edit my answer.

Comment: Fixed the code. I haven't tried it with the actual code, so please make minor changes.

Comment: when I try to update an employee, an error is giving. "WorkExperience matching query does not exist" how can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

How about putting forms into get_context_data?
Something like
context['form1'] = EmployeeAddModelForm()
context['form2] = WorkExperienceForm()
Etc.
Edit:

```
def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(EmployeeUpdateView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['form'] = EmployeeAddModelForm()
        context['form2'] = WorkExperienceForm()
        context['form3'] = EducationForm()
        return context
```

Comment: can you give me the ans little bit elaborately?

Comment: If I do this, I get a blank form. But I want previously filled data for update view

Comment: Try to use initial, for example: context['form'] = EmployeeAddModelForm(initial={'e_id': something })